# How to add MDX where clause?

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

Hi everyone im so new to MDX.

how to add a where clause on this query?

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Tbl VS Master Data Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Tbl VS Master Data].[Financer].[Financer].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Tbl VS Master Data].[Down Payment].[Down Payment].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES     
MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [Vehicle Sales] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, 
BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

This is generated using query builder on report builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your where clause right after the `FROM [Vehicle Sales]`. For example, if you only wanted to see this year you might add a where clause like this:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Tbl VS Master Data Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Tbl VS Master Data].[Financer].[Financer].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Tbl VS Master Data].[Down Payment].[Down Payment].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES     
MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM [Vehicle Sales] 
WHERE ([Date].[Year].&{2014])
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

But be sure that you [actually do want a where clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146047.aspx). If you are using a multivalue parameter in your where clause, you may need to look into subselects depending on what you are going for. You can't use a where clause to filter rows and columns. If you have a set, put the members in brackets.  If you have multiple dimension members to put in your where clause put it in parentheses. See the link for more details.